# Correct usage of the word "my" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, possessive-pronouns

My writing was flowing and this is something that I wrote:

> I pull into my parking spot, which is empty despite **my** having never reserved it, and get out.

I was curious as to whether this usage of the word **my** is grammatically correct, or whether the sentence would make sense without it?

Is **me** acceptable too? It doesn't seem right to me:

> I pull into my parking spot, which is empty despite me having never reserved it, and get out.

I'm assuming that *this* is correct:

> I pull into my parking spot, which is empty despite having never reserved it, and get out.

Or:

> I pull into my parking spot, which is empty despite the fact that I've never reserved it, and get out.

Comment: I believe this is answered by Nohat's answer in the linked question.

Comment: @Andrew Leach♦: There's also the issue of a potential "dangling participle" in OP's version #3 (the one without ***me*** OR ***my***), which I think doesn't arise in the linked question.